# Producer / Consumer using wait and notify

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

I am trying to coordinate a producer and consumer thread problem. The producer puts 10 objects on the queue. That is the producer's run method just includes a simple loop to add 10 objects then it is finished. When the queue is full (queue is size 10) there is a call to wait()  - > in the queue's add method. On the consumer side, the consumer starts by peeking at the objects and then it starts removing them. The problem I am having is that in roughly 50% of cases when the program is ran, the output terminates after the producer puts the 10 objects on queue. The other 50% of times the program works fine - that is the consumer takes off all the objects. My prior solution to this problem was to create a new consumer thread within the producer's run method. So once the producer had put ten objects on queue, the new consumer thread was created and I used join() to synchronize operations. However I would like to get the process working with wait and notify. Can someone please advise what I am doing wrong? thanks

```
    @Override
    public synchronized boolean add(Process element) {
    if(isFull())
    {
        waitForNotify();
    }

    else
    {          

       queue.add(element);



    }
    return true;
}

    private void invokeNotify() {
    try {
        notify();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

    private void waitForNotify() {
    try {
        wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

     @Override
     public synchronized boolean offer(Process element) throws IllegalStateException {
       queue.add(element);
       this.queue = newHeapSort.heapify(queue, queue.size());
       return true;



}

    @Override
    public synchronized Process peek() {
    if(queue.isEmpty())
    {
        waitForNotify();
    }
    return(queue.get(0));

}

    @Override
    public synchronized Process head() {    
    if(queue.isEmpty()) 
    {
        invokeNotify();
    }

        Process head = queue.get(0);
        queue.remove(0);


        return head;


}
```

Answer (score 3):

The producer never notifies the consumer thread. So if the consumer is the first to start, it finds the queue empty, and waits eternally.

I would simply use a BlockingQueue, which does that for you.

If you really want to use `wait()` and `notify()`, you'll need to:

- use a loop around your `wait()` calls, and go back to the waiting state if the condition to wake up is not true
- decide when the producer should notify (normally, when it puts an item in the queue)
- decide when the consumer should notify (normally, when it removes an item from the queue)
- decide when the consumer should wait (normally, when the queue is empty)
- decide when the producer should wait (normally, when the queue is full)
- stop ignoring InterruptedException. Just let them propagate.

I would use `notifyAll()`, which would also make sure that everything works well if there are several producers or consumers.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I will take them into account for future reference. My problem on this occasion was more trivial - the threads were not "started and joined" properly. Thanks again for the tips.